# Fatal error: Call to undefined function tep_session_name()

Tags: php, undefined-function

I am trying to update one of the sites I maintain to the latest PHP and during this, I have come across the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function tep_session_name() in ... /includes/application_top.php on line 83

The code it is referring to is:

```
 // set the session name and save path   
 tep_session_name('osCAdminID');       
 tep_session_save_path(SESSION_WRITE_DIRECTORY);
```

But I have looked at the sessions.php file are the function is defined in the below code:

```
 function tep_session_name($name = '') {
    if ($name != '') {
      return session_name($name);
    } else {
      return session_name();
    }
  }
```

Any help in identifying the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, E.

Comment: You should just rewrite the whole application. How it uses sessions is really bad.

Comment: Holy crap! Is that OS Commerce?! I haven't seen that in the wild for years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely sure, that you call this function before you include file with function declaration

Comment: This is currently how it is in the code, it looks like it is calling it above using it? // define how the session functions will be used
  require(DIR_WS_FUNCTIONS . 'sessions.php');

  // set the session name and save path
  tep_session_name('osCAdminID');
  tep_session_save_path(SESSION_WRITE_DIRECTORY);